# Why does "big = big.add(..)" need to be used to sum BigIntegers?

Tags: java, arrays, addition, biginteger

I am a beginner. This might be a silly question.

I have an array of really big numbers. I need to find the sum of all those numbers in the array. I defined a BigInteger and initialised it to zero. Now I will traverse the array and add each element to this BigInteger.

```
BigInteger big = BigInteger.ZERO;
for(BigInteger b : array){
   big.add(b);
}
```

No compilation error but `big` value was still zero,the code didn't work. So, I checked it up and learnt BigInteger add method returns the sum. I modified above code.

```
big = big.add(b);
```

Now this worked fine.

**My Question**: What actually is happening there? Why didn't the first code update `big` value.

Can I compare this `BigInteger.add()` with `collection.add()`

More insight is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why didn't the first code update big value.

BigInteger is immutable, you can't change it any more than you can change a String, or any primitive wrapper.

e.g.

```
String s = "Hello ";
s.concat("World"); // doesn't change anything.

s = s.concat("World"); // Updates 's'
```

> Can I compare this BigInteger.add() with collection.add()

Collections are mutable, but this scalar value is not.

Using mutable objects is largely a performance concession.  If you have a collection which takes a complete copy each time it would perform very badly.

Comment: @Charan Creating a new collection containing almost exactly the same references as an existing one could be expensive if the collection is large. Mutable collections allow one to get a slightly modified version of a collection without doing that work.

Comment: @Charan To add an element to an ArrayList of one million elements could be as simple as a reference assignment and a counter increment. To copy and add, you have to copy all the references, all million of them just to add one.  BTW CopyOnWriteArrayList does this and is very slow for modifying a large collection.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks, Got it!

Answer (score 4):

This is the JavaDoc for the method

```
public BigInteger add(BigInteger val)
Returns a BigInteger whose value is (this + val).

Parameters:
val - value to be added to this BigInteger.

Returns:
this + val
```

This means that rather than modifying the value, it calculates a new value and returns it. When you perform `big = big.add(b)`, you're running that method, taking the resultant value, and replacing the original value of big with it.

Consider the equivalent using ints, x and y.

```
int x = 3;
int y = 4;
x + y; // At this point, x is still 3 - as you've not assigned the result of this calculation anywhere
x = x + y; // Now - x will be 7
```

Answer (score 2):

> My Question: What actually is happening there? Why didn't the first
>   code update big value.

Because it's *Immutable arbitrary-precision integers* means it won't actually change the original one but create a new one when you call `add` method.Note immutable means for which once the `Object` is created it's state can not be changed.For example `String`,`Integer`,`Float` etc.

```
Integer i = new Integer(10);//State 1
i = new Integer(20);//State 2 but does not update state 1
```

[`big.add(b);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add(java.math.BigInteger)) returns value after addition which you need to store in other or same variable.

See what add method is doing here,

```
public BigInteger add(BigInteger val) {
    if (val.signum == 0)
        return this;
    if (signum == 0)
        return val;
    if (val.signum == signum)
        return new BigInteger(add(mag, val.mag), signum);

    int cmp = compareMagnitude(val);
    if (cmp == 0)
        return ZERO;
    int[] resultMag = (cmp > 0 ? subtract(mag, val.mag)
                       : subtract(val.mag, mag));
    resultMag = trustedStripLeadingZeroInts(resultMag);
    //Here it's creating new Object
    return new BigInteger(resultMag, cmp == signum ? 1 : -1);//<====
}
```

> Can I compare this BigInteger.add() with collection.add()

Here say `List.add` will actually add the element to the list and you can change the value of that element and note `List.add` does not create a new element but it actually adds the reference of original element.